# Cookies are deleted once app ionic 3 closed in android

Tags: ionic-framework, cookies, ionic3

I have an application that works logging in with the api and save the cookies(authentication). Everything works fine, but once you close the application and lunche the application again you find the **'NotLoggedIn'** message and you find that the cookies have been deleted. Any Help ?
thank you...

Comment: Are you using native storage?

Comment: But api works with cookies, how will i make lapi work with local storage token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you I found a solution this is my method of saving cookies value in local storage and I test if the value not null and i set cookies to my website and all it works .
for get and set cookies i use this plugin : [cordova-plugin-cookie-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cookie-polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage instead of cookies

localstorage has following + points

> persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.
>
> with no expiration date,
>
> cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser cache / Locally Stored Data.
>
> Storage limit is the maximum amongst the three.

Set LocalStorage

> localStorage.setItem('userdetails',UserData);

Get LocalStorage

> localStorage.setItem('userdetails');

Comment: But api works with cookies, how will i make lapi work with local storage token

Comment: thank you I found a solution this is my method of saving cookies value in local storage and I test if the value not null and i set cookies to my website and all it works